# New doctrime ORM Table field creater but it says it's still not mapped

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have added a new field/column to my "listing" entity, which is a boolean named "promoted" which is like one already present in the db "certified", it is created to behave exactly the same, however, it is'nt working..
The mariadb db updated correctly with the new row containing a boolean, but when i try to use it in a partial query or to update the field from 0 to 1 with a form it dont update, like it's unmapped, here's my code (not all just the important parts are it is 3 functions with 1000~+ lines: BaseListing.php

```
/**
 * Listing
 *
 * @CocoricoAssert\ListingConstraint()
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseListing
{
    protected $price = 0;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="certified", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $certified;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="min_duration", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var integer
     */

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="promoted", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * 
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $promoted;


    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isCertified()
    {
        return $this->certified;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $certified
     */
    public function setCertified($certified)
    {
        $this->certified = $certified;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isPromoted()
    {
        return $this->promoted;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $promoted
     */
    public function setPromoted($promoted)
    {
        $this->promoted = $promoted;
    }
}
```

here's AdminListing.php to generate the form for the admin panel to pass certified on / off and as i wish promoted on / off (cuted because it's a too large file):

```
class ListingAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    /** @inheritdoc */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('admin.listing.title')
            ->add(
                'status',
                ChoiceType::class,
                array(
                    'choices' => array_flip(Listing::$statusValues),
                    'placeholder' => 'admin.listing.status.label',
                    'translation_domain' => 'cocorico_listing',
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.status.label',
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'adminNotation',
                ChoiceType::class,
                array(
                    'choices' => array_combine(
                        range(0, 10, 0.5),
                        array_map(
                            function ($num) {
                                return number_format($num, 1);
                            },
                            range(0, 10, 0.5)
                        )
                    ),
                    'placeholder' => 'admin.listing.admin_notation.label',
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.admin_notation.label',
                    'required' => false,
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'certified',
                null,
                array(
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.certified.label',
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'promoted',
                CheckboxType::class,
                array(
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.promoted.label',
                    'required' => false,
                )
            )
```

This is not working because i have a query in ListingRepository that use "certified":

```
public function getFindSelectPart(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder)
    {
        $queryBuilder
            ->select("partial l.{id, price, averageRating, certified, createdAt, commentCount}")
            ->addSelect("partial t.{id, locale, slug, title, description}")
            ->addSelect("partial llcat.{id, listing, category}")
            ->addSelect("partial ca.{id, lft, lvl, rgt, root}")
            ->addSelect("partial cat.{id, locale, name}")
            ->addSelect("partial i.{id, name}")
            ->addSelect("partial u.{id, firstName}")
            ->addSelect("partial ln.{id, city, route, country}")
            ->addSelect("partial co.{id, lat, lng}")
            ->addSelect("partial ui.{id, name}")
            ->addSelect("'' AS DUMMY");//To maintain fields on same array level when extra fields are added

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
```

And when i put promoted just behind the certified in the partial query it says:
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 88 near partial.l Error: There is no mapped field named 'promoted' on class Cocorico\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing

besides i have done exactly the same setup as the certified value, i have cleared cache and updated DB scheme.

Here's my Entity\Listing.php :

```
?php

namespace Cocorico\ListingBundle\Entity;

use Cocorico\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking;
use Cocorico\ListingBundle\Model\BaseListing;
use Cocorico\ListingBundle\Model\ListingOptionInterface;
use Cocorico\ListingCategoryBundle\Entity\ListingListingCategory;
use Cocorico\ListingCharacteristicBundle\Entity\ListingListingCharacteristic;
use Cocorico\ListingDiscountBundle\Entity\ListingDiscount;
use Cocorico\ListingImageBundle\Entity\ListingImage;
use Cocorico\ListingLocationBundle\Entity\ListingLocation;
use Cocorico\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread;
use Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Listing
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cocorico\ListingBundle\Repository\ListingRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="listing",indexes={
 *    @ORM\Index(name="created_at_l_idx", columns={"created_at"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="status_l_idx", columns={"status"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="price_idx", columns={"price"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="type_idx", columns={"type"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="min_duration_idx", columns={"min_duration"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="max_duration_idx", columns={"max_duration"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="average_rating_idx", columns={"average_rating"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="admin_notation_idx", columns={"admin_notation"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="platform_notation_idx", columns={"platform_notation"})
 *  })
 */
class Listing extends BaseListing
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Timestampable\Timestampable;
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    use \Cocorico\ListingSearchAdvancedBundle\Model\ListingSearchableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingCategoryFieldBundle\Model\ListingCategoryFieldableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\DeliveryBundle\Model\ListingDeliverableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingDepositBundle\Model\ListingDepositableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingSessionBundle\Model\ListingSessionableTrait;

//    use \Cocorico\ServiceBundle\Model\ListingTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingVideoBundle\Model\ListingVideoTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\CarrierBundle\Model\ListingCarrierableTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Cocorico\CoreBundle\Model\CustomIdGenerator")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="assert.not_blank")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="listings", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingLocationBundle\Entity\ListingLocation", inversedBy="listing", cas\
cade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @var ListingLocation
     **/
    protected $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingCategoryBundle\Entity\ListingListingCategory", mappedBy="listing\
", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)//, fetch="EAGER"
     *
     */
    protected $listingListingCategories;

    /**
     * For Asserts @see \Cocorico\ListingBundle\Validator\Constraints\ListingValidator
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingImageBundle\Entity\ListingImage", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"\
persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "asc"})
     */
    protected $images;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingCharacteristicBundle\Entity\ListingListingCharacteristic", mappe\
dBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true) //, fetch="EAGER"
     *
     */
    protected $listingListingCharacteristics;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingDiscountBundle\Entity\ListingDiscount", mappedBy="listing", casc\
ade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"fromQuantity" = "asc"})
     */
    protected $discounts;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", \
"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "desc"})
     */
    protected $bookings;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"remove"}, o\
rphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "desc"})
     */
    protected $threads;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingBundle\Model\ListingOptionInterface", mappedBy="listing", cascad\
e={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $options;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->listingListingCharacteristics = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->listingListingCategories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->discounts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->threads = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->options = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add characteristics
     *
     * @param  ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addListingListingCharacteristic(ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic)
    {
        $this->listingListingCharacteristics[] = $listingListingCharacteristic;

        return $this;
    }
 /**
     * Remove characteristics
     *
     * @param ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     */
    public function removeListingListingCharacteristic(ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic)
    {
        $this->listingListingCharacteristics->removeElement($listingListingCharacteristic);
        $listingListingCharacteristic->setListing(null);
    }

    /**
     * Get characteristics
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|ListingListingCharacteristic[]
     */
    public function getListingListingCharacteristics()
    {
        return $this->listingListingCharacteristics;
    }

 /**
     * Get characteristics ordered by Group and Characteristic
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getListingListingCharacteristicsOrderedByGroup()
    {
        $iterator = $this->listingListingCharacteristics->getIterator();
        $iterator->uasort(
            function ($a, $b) {
                /**
                 * @var ListingListingCharacteristic $a
                 * @var ListingListingCharacteristic $b
                 */
                $groupPosA = $a->getListingCharacteristic()->getListingCharacteristicGroup()->getPosition();
                $groupPosB = $b->getListingCharacteristic()->getListingCharacteristicGroup()->getPosition();

                $characteristicPosA = $a->getListingCharacteristic()->getPosition();
                $characteristicPosB = $b->getListingCharacteristic()->getPosition();
                if ($groupPosA == $groupPosB) {
                    if ($characteristicPosA == $characteristicPosB) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    return ($characteristicPosA < $characteristicPosB) ? -1 : 1;
                }

                return ($groupPosA < $groupPosB) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        );

        return new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
    }
 /**
     * Add characteristics
     *
     * @param  ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addListingListingCharacteristicsOrderedByGroup(
        ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
    ) {
        return $this->addListingListingCharacteristic($listingListingCharacteristic);
    }


    /**
     * Remove characteristics
     *
     * @param ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     */
    public function removeListingListingCharacteristicsOrderedByGroup(
        ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
    ) {
        $this->removeListingListingCharacteristic($listingListingCharacteristic);
    }
 /**
     * Add category
     *
     * @param  ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addListingListingCategory(ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory)
    {
        $listingListingCategory->setListing($this);
        $this->listingListingCategories[] = $listingListingCategory;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Remove category
     *
     * @param ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory
     */
    public function removeListingListingCategory(ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory)
    {
//        foreach ($listingListingCategory->getValues() as $value) {
//            $listingListingCategory->removeValue($value);
//        }

        $this->listingListingCategories->removeElement($listingListingCategory);
    }
/**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|ListingListingCategory[]
     */
    public function getListingListingCategories()
    {
        return $this->listingListingCategories;
    }


    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param  \Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
 /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Add images
     *
     * @param  ListingImage $image
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addImage(ListingImage $image)
    {
        $image->setListing($this); //Because the owning side of this relation is listing image
        $this->images[] = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove images
     *
     * @param ListingImage $image
     */
    public function removeImage(ListingImage $image)
    {
        $this->images->removeElement($image);
        $image->setListing(null);
    }

    /**
     * Get images
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param  ListingLocation $location
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function setLocation(ListingLocation $location = null)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
        //Needed to persist listing_id on listing_location table when inserting a new listing embedding a listing location form
        $this->location->setListing($this);
    }
/**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return ListingLocation
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }


    /**
     * Add discount
     *
     * @param  ListingDiscount $discount
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addDiscount(ListingDiscount $discount)
    {
        $discount->setListing($this);
        $this->discounts[] = $discount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove discount
     *
     * @param ListingDiscount $discount
     */
    public function removeDiscount(ListingDiscount $discount)
    {
        $this->discounts->removeElement($discount);
        $discount->setListing(null);
    }

    /**
     * Get discounts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDiscounts()
    {
        return $this->discounts;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection|ListingDiscount[] $discounts
     */
    public function setDiscounts(ArrayCollection $discounts)
    {
        foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
            $discount->setListing($this);
        }

        $this->discounts = $discounts;
    }
/**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|Booking[]
     */
    public function getBookings()
    {
        return $this->bookings;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection|Booking[] $bookings
     */
    public function setBookings(ArrayCollection $bookings)
    {
        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
            $booking->setListing($this);
        }

        $this->bookings = $bookings;
    }

    /**
     * Add booking
     *
     * @param Booking $booking
     *
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addBooking(Booking $booking)
    {
        $this->bookings[] = $booking;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove booking
     *
     * @param Booking $booking
     */
    public function removeBooking(Booking $booking)
    {
        $this->bookings->removeElement($booking);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getThreads()
    {
        return $this->threads;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection|Thread[] $threads
     */
    public function setThreads(ArrayCollection $threads)
    {
foreach ($threads as $thread) {
            $thread->setListing($this);
        }

        $this->threads = $threads;
    }

    /**
     * Add thread
     *
     * @param Thread $thread
     *
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addThread(Thread $thread)
    {
        $this->threads[] = $thread;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove thread
     *
     * @param Thread $thread
     */
    public function removeThread(Thread $thread)
    {
        $this->threads->removeElement($thread);
    }

    /**
     * Add ListingOption
     *
     * @param  ListingOptionInterface $option
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addOption($option)
    {
        $option->setListing($this);
        $this->options[] = $option;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove ListingOption
     *
     * @param ListingOptionInterface $option
     */
    public function removeOption($option)
    {
        $this->options->removeElement($option);
    }foreach ($threads as $thread) {
            $thread->setListing($this);
        }

        $this->threads = $threads;
    }

    /**
     * Add thread
     *
     * @param Thread $thread
     *
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addThread(Thread $thread)
    {
        $this->threads[] = $thread;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove thread
     *
     * @param Thread $thread
     */
    public function removeThread(Thread $thread)
    {
        $this->threads->removeElement($thread);
    }

    /**
     * Add ListingOption
     *
     * @param  ListingOptionInterface $option
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addOption($option)
    {
        $option->setListing($this);
        $this->options[] = $option;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove ListingOption
     *
     * @param ListingOptionInterface $option
     */
    public function removeOption($option)
    {
        $this->options->removeElement($option);
    }
/**
     * Get ListingOptions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $options
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setOptions(ArrayCollection $options)
    {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $option->setListing($this);
        }

        $this->options = $options;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @param int  $minImages
     * @param bool $strict
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCompletionInformations($minImages, $strict = true)
    {
        $characteristic = 0;
        foreach ($this->getListingListingCharacteristics() as $characteristics) {
            if ($characteristics->getListingCharacteristicValue()) {
                $characteristic = 1;
            }
        }

        return array(
            "title" => $this->getTitle() ? 1 : 0,
            "description" => (
                ($strict && $this->getDescription()) ||
                (!$strict && strlen($this->getDescription()) > 250)
            ) ? 1 : 0,
            "price" => $this->getPrice() ? 1 : 0,
            "image" => (
                ($strict && count($this->getImages()) >= $minImages) ||
                (!$strict && count($this->getImages()) > $minImages)
            ) ? 1 : 0,
            "characteristic" => $characteristic,
        );
    }
public function getTitle()
    {   
        return (string)$this->translate()->getTitle();
    }

    public function getSlug()
    {   
        return (string)$this->translate()->getSlug();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->getTitle();
    }
    /**
     * To add impersonating link into admin :
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getImpersonating()
    {
        return $this->getUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should probably add the Listing class as well, not just BaseListing. If you happen to override the field, that would explain a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi, where should i add the listing class ? in the listingAdmin class?

Comment: you should add it to your question. The error message mentions the Listing class, but you omitted that class from your question.

Comment: Hey @Jakumi i added it to my question, do you have some advice please ?

Comment: tbh, I don't see anything wrong with this. So my advice would be - as usual - scrap the cache and warm it up again. also in case it's relevant, see that your migration runs on the same database that you're using when the error previously occurred - there can be "funny" effects, when commands use .env and the web server uses the given environment vars from the server.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies unfortunately i have done all what you tell me :/